# Grep a string from the same file in multiple .tar.gz files

Tags: grep, search, archive

I have multiple *.tar.gz files. They all contain files with file name a, b, and c. Is there a way to grep string 'foo' only from file b under these multiple *.tar.gz files without extracting the files.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that by "without extracting" you mean "without saving extracted files to disk":

```
for file in *.tar.gz ; do
    tar xzOf $file b | grep --label=$file/b -H foo
done
```

tar options:

`x` extract
`z` gunzip before extracting
`O` dump to stdout rather than creating file (capital letter oh, not number zero)
`f` from specified tar file

grep options (suggested by JJoao)

`--label=...` use specified label as the filename
`-H` print filename for each match

Answer (score 1):

The command `zgrep` works on .tar.gz files without extracting the contents.